# How do I bypass the speed limiter on a Suzuki GSF1200 (Bandit)?

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, rev-limiter

How do I bypass the speed limiter on a Suzuki GSF1200 (Bandit)?

From what I understand, the limitter is only activated on 5th gear and then on the revolutions (about 7000). This limmitation is only for Japan and I live in South Africa. Somebody told me that it can be done with a resistor and some wire, but I am not sure how it is done.

Can somebody help with more information regarding this or point me to a link or something of assistance?

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Will you inform the insurance company of the modification?

Comment: It is an old bike, I only have third party insurance on it and would like to remove the limiter for track days.

Comment: So, you mean a track bike only or is it still likely to go on the road...

Comment: It will still likely go on the road. But the bike was a "grey import", the reason for having the speed limiter, other bikes in our country are not limited.

Comment: Those people at your track days will probably be able to show you or do it in 5 mins...

Comment: Thanks, I will try again, but haven't have success yet, because it is an older bike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find you need to put a 1.5K ohm resistor in the speed sensor circuit.

A wiring diagram and multimeter are your friend with this. Hope this helps.

The posts which may also help you can be found at: https://www.boards.ie/b/thread/2055162677

Also, this is applicable to the jap 750 version but I wouldn't dismiss it:

A lot of the 750 jap imports had a number of restrictions, not just a speed restriction.

- cdi restricted, replace with a gsxr750/bandit 6/12 cdi
- intake restrictors. replace or carve out the restricted one
- carb, these were often jetted quite lean etc
- exhaust, sometimes there was a restrictor welded into the top part of the exhaust, worth checking to see if its there